# Ejecutar funciones de manera secuencial javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp

tengo un problema con el orden de ejecucion de un codigo Javascript ya que el mismo no espera que termine una funcion y para a ejecutar las siguientes lineas de codigo. lo que necesito es que sea de manera secuencial ya que por ejemplo: los datos de la funcion1() son necesarios para la funcion2(). El dilema es que las funciones llaman a .asp que conectan con mi BD y las mismas tienen consultas muy pesadas las cuales demoran tiempos variados dependiendo de cada funcion. les dejo un codigo

```js
function Secciones(anio) {
    $.getJSON
    (
        "Secciones.asp",// URL del servicio
        {
            anio: anio
        },   // Parámetros
        function (data) {   // Función callback
            var elem = $("#idSeccion");
            elem.empty(); // Limpiamos el contenedor
            var s = "";
            s += "<option value='0' selected='selected'>- seleccione -</option>"
            $.each(data.Secciones, function (i, item) {
                s += "<option value='" + item.idSeccion + "-" + item.idModalidad + "'>" + item.detalle + "</option>"
            });
            elem.html(s);   // Insertamos la lista en el contenedor
        }
    );
}

function ListaDeAlumnos(idSeccion) {
    $.getJSON
    (
        "ListaDeAlumnos.asp",// URL del servicio
        {
            seccion: idSeccion,
            anio: $("#idCiclo").val()
        },   // Parámetros
        function (data) {   // Función callback
            var elem = $("#idListaAlumnos");
            elem.empty(); // Limpiamos el contenedor
            var s = "";
            s += "<option value='0' selected='selected'>- seleccione -</option>"
            var cont = 0;
            $.each(data.ListaAlumnos, function (i, item) {
                s += "<option value='" + item.idAlumno + "'>" + item.Documento + " - " + item.ApellidoNombre + "</option>"
                cont += 1;
            });
            elem.html(s);   // Insertamos la lista en el contenedor
        }
    );
}

function principal(){
    var anio = 2018;
    Secciones(anio);
    alert("termino la primera funcion");
    var seccion = $("#idSeccion").val();
    ListaDeAlumnos(seccion);
    alert("termino la segunda funcion");
}
```

cuando llamo a mi funcion "principal()" lo que sucede es que se ejecutan los 2 alert y luego los Json.
Lo que necesito es que necesariamente se ejecute la primera funcion para luego pasar a la segunda ya que necesito el dato "$("#idSeccion").val();" para pasarselo a la segunda

Comment: Tendrias que llamar a la funcion `ListaDeAlumnos()` en el callback de `Secciones()`

Comment: puedes hacerlo atraves de callbacks, usar la [api fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) o usando [asyn y await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) o utilizando promesas la mas simple [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/then)

Comment: si usas await antes de llamar la funcion el flujo principal no sigue. creo que es justo lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el .then detrás de cada función, el código que incluya el then se ejecutará al terminar la función.

```
Secciones(anio).then(function() {
    alert("termino la primera funcion");
};
```

Lo que necesitas es el uso de promesas, te dejo aqui una explicación de su uso:

[Usar promesas - Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas)

Comment: Gracias compañero!. me instruire en el tema. mil gracias

Comment: Ey Demy.
mira como lo modifique mas abajo. tengo un nuevo problema aplicando promesas.-

Comment: Buenas Juan, es un tema algo complejo esto de las promesas, el return de tu función secciones debe ser una promesa, no te preocupes si esa función ya devuelve algo, ya que esa promesa te lo va a proporcionar, te paso otro enlace que posiblemente te aclare un poco más:

https://anexsoft.com/ejemplo-practico-de-promise-con-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando "promesas" el codigo me quedaria asi segun como lei en el enlace que me pasaron

```js
function exitoCallback(resultado) {
    alert("con exito");
}

function falloCallback(error) {
    alert("sin exito");
}

function Secciones(anio) {
    $.getJSON
    (
        ...
    );
}

function ListaDeAlumnos(idSeccion) {
    $.getJSON
    (
        ...
    );
}

function principal(){
    var anio = 2018;
    Secciones(anio).then(exitoCallback, falloCallback);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="idPruebas" onclick ="pasarValores();" value="Accion">
```

el error que me aparece es que al ejecutar el codigo, en la consola del navegador me aparece el error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"